# Replacing text by stars same length preserving whitespace with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I got following request: I want to replace substrings in a text with stars of same length using PHP. The substrings are masked with `<protected>` tags. I already found a solution for this but I want to go a step further: algorithm should preserve whitespace, for example blanks or line breaks.

I'll make an example. Input:

```
This is an example for <protected>hidden text
that's not covering one
not two
but four whole lines!</protected> Wow!
```

Expected result:

```
This is an example for ****** **** 
****** *** ******** ***
*** ***
*** **** ***** ****** Wow!
```

What I got so far:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/<protected>(.*)<\/protected>/is',
    function ($matches) {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[1]));
    }, $input);
```

Gives (of course):

```
This is an example for ***************************************************************** Wow!
```

Have you guys got any idea how to reach this? Hasn't to use regex necessarily.

Comment: How about changing the regex so that it only searches for everything else than white space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\S` (matches anything but whitespace):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~<protected>(.*)</protected>~is',
  function ($m) { return preg_replace('/\S/', '*', $m[1]); }, $input);
```

**output:**

```
This is an example for ****** ****
****** *** ******** ***
*** ***
*** **** ***** ****** Wow!
```

Answer (score 1):

For the challenge:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)(?<!</protected>)|<protected>)\S(\s*)(?:</protected>)?~';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '*\1', $str);
```

But an approach that extracts first the content between `<protected>` tags is better in my opinion.

Comment: This is a great idea, probably of not so great performance and not too easy to understand and read. Played around with [a similar one](https://regex101.com/r/fU3xJ8/1). However it's a great answer, because I learned from it at a high regex skill (how to break the contiguity by use of the negative lookbehind).

Answer (score 0):

```
$newText = preg_replace_callback('/<protected>(.*)<\/protected>/is',
    function ($matches) {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[1]));
    }, $input);
$newText = str_replace(' ', '*', $newText);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php